# How do I rename a Qt Visual studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I want to rename my Qt Visual studio project. I tried renaming the project folder and the vcxproj files. I replaced all the instances of the old project name inside the vcxproj files manually. I also replaced all the instances of the old project name inside the qrc files. I have done this before with other non-Qt visual studio projects, and it has worked successfully. However, with this project I am getting the following error.

```
MSB4181: the "QtRunWork" task returned false but did not log an error. (qt_globals.target 293)
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Edit your `CMakeList.txt` or are you using `QMake` instead of `CMake`?

Comment: not using either. I created the solution through visual studio.

Comment: In general, it's often useful to do something like `grep -r "name of old project"` and see where it's getting referenced. There might be other config/build files that need to be changed as well.